# Alt Z, or showing the material colors [material view] seem to have stopped working

Tags: materials

---

**render view**

[image]

**materials view**

[image]

**texture view**

[image]

**solid view**

[image]

---

Didn't go out of Cycles render, am not aware of doing any changes, what's happening? Now the only way that colors show is through Render view.
I'm cycling through posemode and edit mode BTW when this happened, any clues?

Comment: Have you tried restarting Blender or your computer?

Comment: i did but no, didn't fix any...

Comment: but i observed the obect is the only thing not displaying colors

Comment: and the colors also show in texture paint mode >> materials view

Comment: and i even need to render in viewport :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you stated that the only thing exhibiting that behavior is one object, you could try checking the object's *Maximum Draw Type* and set it to *Textured*. This setting can be found in *Properties panel > Object tab > Display > Maximum Draw Type*.

[image: Blender]

If that doesn't help, you can also upload the .blend file to [here](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com) and allow the community to take a look at it.

Comment: OK, i'll try that

Comment: WOW, ok thanks! now its fixed!!!
but now i wonder how it ended like that?
maybe i pressed button combinations of its shortcut? is there?